# take returned data out of ajax post function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make a condition based on data returned from an ajax post outside the post function

```
function post(){

   $.post('page.php',$('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
   if(data !== 'good'){alert(data); return false;} // take this out of here
});
    //and place it here

}
```

Comment: You can make ajax work in synchronous way, but are you sure you want to do that? That is not the best idea and you should better change your logic so it will be ok to do something based on data received inside success callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code like below should work fine.

```
function post(){
   var data;
   $.ajax({url:'page.php',
           async:false,
           type:'POST',
           data:$('#form').serialize(), 
           success:function(res) {
                 data = res;
           }
     });
     if(data !== 'good'){alert(data); return false;} // take this out of here
}
```

But remember that synchronous ajax call will freeze your page until request is done and you may find it better to find a way how to do what you need without moving `if(data !== 'good'){alert(data); return false;}` outside success callback function.

**UPD**: missed to specify request type, which should be `POST` instead of default `GET`. Code updated.

Comment: thank you, I did try to find a way to do it inside the post function, but there were always problems, so I had to find another way.